# Bootstrap dropdown position fixed with container border-radius vanishing beyond border in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I believe I've came across a bug in IE involving overflow and border-radius. I'm hoping to find a way to solve it without removing border-radius.

This jsfiddle shows the problem I'm having in IE9 & 10(condensed as much as possible):

http://jsfiddle.net/b3XA2/7/

if you click in the one of the boxes a menu will show up where you clicked. Difference is the first box the menu will not escape the borders of the box.

This is caused by:

```
.one {
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Which I need as the content in the first div may exceed it's height limitations and I want it to scroll if it does.

Removing the overflow-y or border-radius fixes this issue.

Comment: Is JavaScript involved on your actual page?

Comment: Yes very similarly too, except on contextmenu instead of click events.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to use JavaScript to move the `ul` element to be a child of `body` when you click (and move it back afterwards if needed when the `ul` is hidden). Since you're setting it to `position: fixed; top: Xpx; left: Xpx`, it shouldn't make a difference visually. Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/b3XA2/9/. I realise that it's a bad solution, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Or, do you need `position: relative` on `#menu`? If not: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/b3XA2/10/

Comment: A little more information: I'm using meteor, and in order for the context to be set right it needs to stay where it is, inside the div. The position: relative is set by bootstrap, I'm not sure what for though. I'll have to experiment a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting overflow for the container, I set it to the ul and made that fill it's parent.
See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b3XA2/11/

```
.one > ul{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I did almost this, instead I wrapped .one's contents in a div and put overflow-y:auto; on that div, and put overflow-y:visible; on .one Thanks!